# How do I show a warning when server is over capacity to avoid server goes down?

Tags: security, capacity

Twitter sometimes shows an message: `Twitter is over capacity`

This is to prevent too much pressure on the servers. Which avoids that the servers go down.

How do I implement this in my application?

Edit: I am NOT looking for a PHP specific solution.

Comment: The best way is to use a non-blocking server (AKA: not Apache) so you won't really be put in this situation with sane levels of traffic...  Then this becomes a non-problem (again, for sane levels of traffic).  If it does start becoming a problem, you can simply implement a 500 error handler to show the pretty page...

Comment: read the following

http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php

Comment: @Oliver: That returns the memory usage of the current process or thread (worker model and operating system dependent), and really has no bearing (as far as I can tell anyway) on the overall system load.  You'd need to use something like [`sys_getloadavg`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.sys-getloadavg.php) for that...

Comment: Isn't that PHP specific?

Comment: If you are not looking for a PHP specific solution, use a load balancer and determine when to give the use your failanimal of choice

Comment: @Enrico: That comment was made when the question was still tagged with `php`, so it was relevant at the time...

Comment: @ircmaxell, yea, sorry about that.. I retagged it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing this can be easily achieved by using a separate software to watch the server status, and on to much pressure, show the specified message. This is very important in a cloud architecture, so you can easily launch new instances. I think Amazon uses CloudWatch for this. Also, you could use [apache mod_status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_status.html) to watch the server, also using a separate software.

Hope this helps, Gabriel